# Can I drill drainage holes on the side of the container?

Tags: containers, drainage

This is a cross-section of a container. Most containers have a drainage hole on the bottom. I've marked that hole with an asterisk.

```
|         |
|         |
|         |
 \___*___/
```

The problem with this position is that you have to elevate the pot with a stand and put a saucer under it or else water flow will be blocked by the pot's bottom forming a seal with the floor.

Can I drill the holes on the sides near the bottom so that I don't need a stand and saucer?

```
|         |
|         |
|         |
*\_______/*
```

Is there a reason why nobody does this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a reason, and its a pretty obvious one. Holes in the bottom of the pot ensure that no water is left sitting at the bottom - holes in the side, even if you get really close to the base, will inevitably leave a millimetre or so undrained. You could probably get round that by using horticultural grit or gravel at the bottom of the pot though, it would certainly help, but the water in the last millimetre or two will always sit there.

I'd just like to add that you don't need to have only one drainage hole in the bottom, you usually only see that in ceramic or terracotta pots, most pots made of other materials have several, smaller holes in the base, and the water will drain out even if the pot is sitting on a solid surface.